# strtof("2147483647", NULL) - conversion string to float (c++)

Tags: type-conversion

Why the result of `strtof` is not as expected ?

```
# include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << std::fixed << std::strtof("2147483647", NULL) << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::fixed << std::strtod("2147483647", NULL) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2147483648.000000
2147483647.000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float` rounds the integers exceeding 16777216 to a power of 2 => `float` is not capable to store 2147483647.000000, it stores 2147483648.000000 instead.